# Apply template on preceding-sibling of following sibling of current node

Tags: xslt

Hi I have following Input

```
<Root>
    <A rename="yes"/>
    <B rename="no"/>
    <C rename="no"/>
    <D rename="yes"/>
    <E rename="no"/>
    <F all="yes"/>
</Root>
```

Currently i am at `<A>` and i want apply template on the element whose `@rename="yes"`, that is coming before element  `<F>`.

i am trying to doing something like:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=
 "following-sibling::*[@all='yes']/preceding-sibling::node()[@rename='yes'" />
```

But i am not getting the expected output. Please suggest.

Comment: So you want to apply templates to all elements with `@rename=yes`? What output are you expecting?

Comment: I just want to take control over `<D rename="yes">` and it could be any element, basically that element whose attribute `@rename='yes' `and followed by `<F>`.

Comment: The input in the question is not well formed.

Comment: You mean over D and A as well?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and simple one-liner-XPath expression solution and its verification using XSLT. :) I also formatted in your question your XML document and other, invisible strings so that the question is now completely readable.

Comment: @Dip, next time please show what output you were getting and what output you were expecting. Your verbal description is unclear (you said 'the element whose @rename="yes" coming before element `<F>`' instead of "the *last* element whose ..."). Elements A and D both fit that description but you used a singular. Seeing the actual data helps clear up those ambiguities.

Answer (score 4):

> Currently i am at `<A>` and i want
>   apply template on the element whose
>   `@rename="yes"`, that is coming before
>   element `<F>`

**You want this XPath expression** (assuming `A` has only one following sibling named `F`):

```
following-sibling::F/preceding-sibling::*[@rename='yes'][1]
```

It selects any element whose `rename` attribute has value of `"yes"` and that is the first such preceding sibling of any following sibling (of the current node) element named `F`.

**Here is a complete XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="A">
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="found" select=
     "following-sibling::F/preceding-sibling::*[@rename='yes'][1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="found">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Root>
    <A rename="yes"/>
    <B rename="no"/>
    <C rename="no"/>
    <D rename="yes"/>
    <E rename="no"/>
    <F all="yes"/>
</Root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<D rename="yes"/>
```

Comment: thanks a Lot Dimitre. It worked. :) I was nearby the right track, but you got on me on the right track. :-)

Comment: +1, I got what the OP requested just looking at your answer :)